# How to rotate circularly (360º) a polygon (square) touching the screen?

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

Actually i have an application that creates a square (a polygon, not a cube, a square) and the user can rotate it touching the screen, but something is going bad, because the rotation is not fair, it only can rotate it horizontally and vertically, but not circularly. I need that the user can rotate it circularly too.

I use this code to do the rotation (horizontal/vertical)

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Current Modelview Matrix

    //Drawing
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, z);         //Move z units into the screen
    gl.glScalef(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);          //Scale the Cube to 80 percent, otherwise it would be too large for the screen

    //Rotate around the axis based on the rotation matrix (rotation, x, y, z)
    gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //X
    gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //Y

    square.draw(gl);                    //Draw the Cube 

    //Change rotation factors
    xrot += xspeed;
    yrot += yspeed;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        //If a touch is moved on the screen
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            //Calculate the change
            float dx = x - oldX;
            float dy = y - oldY;
            //Define an upper area of 10% on the screen
            int upperArea = this.getHeight() / 10;

            //Zoom in/out if the touch move has been made in the upper
            if(y < upperArea) {
                z -= dx * TOUCH_SCALE / 2;

            //Rotate around the axis otherwise
            } else {                
                xrot += dy * TOUCH_SCALE;
                yrot += dx * TOUCH_SCALE;
            }        

        //A press on the screen
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //Define an upper area of 10% to define a lower area
            int upperArea = this.getHeight() / 10;
            int lowerArea = this.getHeight() - upperArea;

            //Change the light setting if the lower area has been pressed 
            if(y > lowerArea) {

            }
        }

        //Remember the values
        oldX = x;
        oldY = y;

        //We handled the event
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
  yourRootLayout.setOnClickListener(yourListener);
  yourAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
  yourAnimation.setDuration(duration in milliseconds - int);

@Override

protected void onClick(View view){

   if (view.getId() == R.id.yourRootLayoutId){

       yourRootLayout.startAnimation(yourAnimation);

   }

}
```